# Retrieving an image from the browser cache with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, browser, cross-domain

I'd like to use [Color Thief](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/), a small Javascript library to extract the dominant color of an image.

The problem is that I load the image on the page from a different server, and Javascript cannot access it (otherwise it would violate the Cross-Origin policy). Is there a way to get the image from the browser instead, since it has already downloaded it?

Note: the server from which I load the image is not under my control, so I cannot make use of CORS.

Comment: Short answer is no ... whatever is cached is cached by domain and you can't directly access it anyway

Comment: @charlietfl Maybe cache is not the right term. I mean, I embed an image in my page with `<img src="..." />` and later I'd like to process it with Javascript. At that time the browser has surely already downloaded the image. Is there a way to access it?

Comment: to be honest I don't even see where CORS relates to an image you are trying to manipulate

Comment: @charlietfl because the library uses `<canvas>` which is being "tainted" if image isn't provided with CORS enabled header.

Comment: @rubik if the image breaks the CORS, you're screwed. But have you tried to set the `crossorigin` property of your `<img>` tag to `Anonymous` ? Or you may have a little luck if the server allows cross-origin requests from xhr

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you Kaiido, I'll try what you suggested!